# Dynamically setting min-width using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, css

I want to dynamically setting the table width using jquery. The below code works fine in Chrome. But in IE and firefox it is not working.

```
var minWidth = 2000;
$("#SimProKendoGrid table").css("cssText", "min-width:" + minWidth +"px"+ "!important");
```

Regards,
Vishnu

Comment: Have you tried reading jquery documentation, specificaly the css function ? http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#SimProKendoGrid table").css("min-width", minWidth + "px !important");
```

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, "!important" can't be added here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var minWidth = 2000;
$("#SimProKendoGrid table").css({"min-width": minWidth + "px"});
```

You should really add curly braces to the css function as if you change more than one attribute then they are necessary. The colon needs to be outside of the quotes as you passing an object (kind of a key/value pair) min-width and its value 2000px. You also cannot have the !important in the css function.

Comment: Still not working in IE and Firefox. Please can you help.

Comment: Then the issue is probably not this line. Can you provide a url or a jsfiddle?